# Uploading files to Web Application in a sub-dirctory using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, subdirectory

I made an ASP.NET MVC web application that is existed in a Sub-Directory. The problem is every time I try to upload file I get this error "**Could not find a part of the path**".

The code is working perfectly on my local machine and other web apps, so I think the problem is related to the web app being exist in the sub-directory, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

This is my function

```
public byte newImage(HttpPostedFileBase newFile, string uploadPath)
        {
            if (newFile != null && newFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (newFile.ContentLength > 3000000) //means file size maximum is 3 MB
                    return 1;   //means the file size is more than 3 MB
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(newFile.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadPath), fileName);
                newFile.SaveAs(path);
                return 0;   //means file uploaded successfuly
            }
            return 2;   //means no file was chosen
        }//Upload New Image
```

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: I added my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong. It seems I forgot to add `~` -_-

So if anyone faced this error, first check if you forgot to add `~`. I suppose it worked well on my local machine and other web apps because they were on the root, but once it's placed on a sub-directory, We need to use relative path using this tilde `~`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you "map" the upload folder properly? You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
DirectoryInfo yourUploadDir = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/YourUploadFolder"));
```

Comment: Well, it seems I didn't. I made my search and found this link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/99aadd/working-with-the-directoryinfo-class-in-C-Sharp/

I'm not sure how to use `DirectoryInfo Class` to solve my problem, so If you can give me extra tip, that would be great.